# Did Ted Nugent dodge the draft?

Tags: war, vietnam-war, music, vietnam

I've asked whether this is in scope: [Are draft-dodgers in scope?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377/are-draft-dodgers-in-scope). I'm not sure,but I'll crack on anyway.

Too what extent did [Ted Nugent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ted_Nugent) dodge the draft for Vietnam. He certainly did receive deferments but was there anything that would qualify [Draft evasion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draft_evasion). Also, the [wikipedia talk page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Ted_Nugent#Self_admitted_draft_dodger) suggests he deficated in his pants for a week to this end, based on an interview he apparently gave. Is any of this backed by by evidence and how good is any of that evidence.

Thanks very much, I feel it's weird that his wikipedia page makes no mention of Vietnam and I need to know whether this omission is correct or needing change.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I feel like this question tows a fine line. On the one hand, Ted Nugent is certainly "famous," but is he the kind of famous that will be remembered long after he is dead? I'm thinking along the lines of say JFK, Louis Armstrong, Marlon Brando, Albert Einstein, etc.

Comment: @ihtkwot: Since there is nowadays such great (and justified, don't get me wrong) interest in "people's history", why not Ted Nugent?

Comment: This might be better recieved on politics.se. I don't think a lot of folks feel The Nuge is (or will be) a figure of much historical importance.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg, yeah I don't really have a good answer for why not the Nuge. That is why I gave the question an upvote, and hopefully someone can find an answer.

Comment: By the way guys, be careful of saying anything libellous guys. Don't answer this one of the top of your head.

Comment: http://www.snopes.com/politics/military/nugent.asp - may answer this later, just to tie up lose ends. Will be very inconclusive.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ted Nugent registered for the draft, showed up to his physical, did not go to Canada, but was classified 4F.  So as someone who was around during Vietnam, I would maintain he is not a draft dodger.

[Government records show Nugent originally got a student deferment in 1969 and when student deferments were ended, he got a 4-F designation that he was "not qualified for military service," which could be for medical or mental reasons.](https://www.indystar.com/story/news/2015/06/03/fact-checker-ted-nugent-a-draft-dodger/28324501/)

However, by his own admission in 1977, Nugent worked hard to get his 4F rating.  He faked symptoms, didn't wash, and starved himself.  ([In a latter interview he refuted this admission](https://www.indystar.com/story/news/2015/06/03/fact-checker-ted-nugent-a-draft-dodger/28324501/))

If he did what he said he did in the first interview with "High Times Magazine in 1977", some folks might call that draft dodging.. I wouldn't.. but nor would I call it honorable.

In the 1960's I might call it common, as many disagreed with the war and actively tried to avoid the draft.   The most ambitious where those who did not register, did not report, and even fled to Canada.. ( Carter would grant these men amnesty in the 1970's)...   I call those pardoned men draft dodgers and Nugent wasn't one.

Comment: If you work hard at not getting drafted, that’s draft dodging by definition.

Comment: I disagree,  there is a difference between someone who says gets a few deferments, ending up in him not serving,  someone who shows up and tries not to be selected,  and someone who burns their card, doesn't show up at the physical, and flee's to Canada.   But perhaps we are just from different times.

Comment: It’s really about intent, and the intent is the same in all the cases. If you are trying to avoid getting drafted, you are dodging the draft, regardless of how you do it, who you are, or the times you are in.

Comment: Well his "intent" was to avoid service.  So for you perhaps he's a draft dodger then.  The law, however; says you have to register for the draft,  you have to get your physical when called, and if called you have to serve.  If you do these things your "intent" doesn't matter.   That's what the law says.  If you clump people who tried to avoid service in with folks who relocated to Canada,  half the folks in the conflict would have been confined.

Comment: When I was a boy of 12 in the late 60's, my father, a career military officer, pulled every string he had to get my older brother into the reserves so he wouldn't get sent to Vietnam. That was my first clue that something wasn't right about that conflict. By 1970, it was obvious to most that the war was a colossal waste, so avoiding getting sent there wasn't unpatriotic, it was common sense. A couple of prominent people who used every legal option at their disposal to avoid military service during that time were Bill Clinton and Donald Trump.

Comment: Yes you are right. And Dick Cheney got 5 deferments  and George  W Bush opted to go int the air force reserves an option most young men without political connections where not afforded.

Comment: Great work +1. I'll accept this if you can link your sources. "Dodging" is colloquial, I mean "evasion", which includes attempting to fair a medical. Whether or not this evasion was from cowardliness or from principle is hard to discern (and not in the scope of this question), but I imagine one would look into the individuals statements and later attitudes to wars that wouldn't so directly threaten their personal safety (etc).

Comment: Good History.SE answers (and comments) avoid arguing over subjective terms such as "draft dodger" and instead presents the objective information in its historical context.

Comment: I think a comparison to the distinction between *tax avoidance* and *tax evasion* is appropriate. *Tax Avoidance* is, properly, the ***duty*** of all tax paying citizens; *Tax Evasion* is a ***felony***. There are cases where the distinction is subtle, but those are actually rare. Nugent clearly *avoided* the draft, but, according to this account, did not *evade* it.

Comment: I also dispute Nugent's assertion that his deliberate actions *caused* his 4F. The Army is well aware of how to *fatten up* a new recruit, and had whole *fattening farms* during World War Two that specialized in putting ten or fifteen pounds of muscle on a new recruit